# running executable (windows) file inside ocaml

Tags: ocaml, exe

Quick question. How to run an executable file in ocaml? I believe this is possible, but I don't know how.

Please provide an example code.

Comment: Take a look at, the manual regarding the `Unix` module. http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual035.html

Comment: Or `Sys.command` for simplest cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to run a program and not communicate with it, use [`Sys.command`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Sys.html#VALcommand).

```
let exit_code = Sys.command "c:\\path\\to\\executable.exe /argument" in
(* if exit_code=0, the command succeeded. Otherwise it failed. *)
```

For more complex cases, you need to use the [functions in the `Unix` module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#6_Highlevelprocessandredirectionmanagement). Despite the name, [most of them](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual035.html) work under Windows. For example, if you need to get output from a command:

```
let ch = Unix.open_process_in "c:\\path\\to\\executable.exe /argument" in
try
  while true do
    let line = input_line ch in …
  done
with End_of_file ->
  let status = close_process_in ch in …
```